# Bigger chart with highcharts

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts, highcharts

I´m working on a chart and it works so beautiful. I´m working with bar chart and I have 5 elements. 
The company needs 20 elements on the chart, and and I did it, but it looks creepy. I need to rezise the area of the chart maybe with the height property. with the width property I have not problem. I tried to resize the div but it didnt work.

Suggestions please?

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see how you are setting things up?

Comment: Add your code we will modify it.

Comment: You should be able to change the size directly in your container, look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/654ooa2n/ If it will not help, please show working example of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a css like this it will work definitely.

```
#yourChartId{
 hight:    //define the size as your wish
 width:    //define the size as your wish
}
```